# Very slow http requests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

We have started to develop a production with nuxt. Everything is perfect except http requests' time.

In postman, one request is taking about 100ms. But in product it is 3000ms and page load time is almost 30sec. What's the problem? Are there anybody faced this kind of issue.

Comment: Are you even sure it's client side? Look at the waterfall on the network tab of dev tools, between that and the performance benchmarks for the painting/rendering parts of the client side should help delimit the culprit but before digging into the client side check the TTFB on the response and make sure it's even your primary concern first.

Comment: We are requesting to our api and wp-json api. each wp-json api takes almost 3 seconds (I see in netwoek tab when route changed.) But in real, or postman, these requests doesnt take 3 seconds. I am pretty sure there is problem. BECAUSE; we have same product with VUE only and there is 16 post/get request when page loading. And no problem. Page load time is 2-3 seconds.

Comment: This is one of those ones where it would be pretty tough to diagnose without being able to recreate it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check network -> Throttling: 
[image]

may be you select a slow connection emulation.

Comment: I wish :) But not select

Answer (score 0):

*(Sorry to be writing as an answer, but I don't have yet enough reputation to comment.)*

Are you in 'universal' mode or spa?
If you are in 'universal' then the first call will run the Server-Side-Rendering and build the html. Make sure you are using asyncData when calling the data, to avoid issues.

A (crude) way to test is to go manually to a product page in a browser, and then navigate to another via a

```html
<nuxt-link />
```

This will first generate the SSR html page, and then will hydrate the page with javascript. So the first call is generated, but the next ones are already the app running.

If the delay is present whe you navigate to the second page, it may be a problem with the request. If its fast, then it may be related to SSR, or a component.

Comment: We are running in universal mode. Both you said ways are delayed. This is very interesting. I am searching.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use asyncData in components? Did you use nuxtServerInit? More information please...

Try to use api call for home page only with `nuxtServerInit`. Further data should come over with `asyncData`